# Modelling Time in java

Tags: java, object

I need to model a 7 day time in java to build a room reservation system

The days are in enumerated Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday and Sunday.

Hours and Minutes.

What is the best way to model this in java?

I tried using multi-dimensional arrays but not sure how to put the enums in.

Comment: Why not using java.util.Calendar?

Comment: @Aubin: Because it's a terrible, terrible API? Joda Time (http://joda-time.sf.net) is much better.

Comment: Why adding more and more external dependencies for a very basic needs covered by the JDK itself?

Comment: it's a school project. i only need to maintain 7 days each time i run the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) is a very popular library for modelling time in Java which you should investigate.  Depending on the details of your requirements, you'll either be interested in an [Interval](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_interval.html) (which represents the time between two instants, i.e. 09:00 on Monday 18th March 2013 UTC to 18:00 on Sunday 24th March 2013 UTC), or a [Period](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_period.html) (which represents concepts like 'a week', or 'a month').

From the information you've given, it sounds to me that Period is probably what you want.  By way of a very brief example, the following code prints out the DateTime (effectively a timestamp), one week from now:

```
    import org.joda.time.DateTime;
    import org.joda.time.Period;

    ...

    DateTime now = new DateTime();
    DateTime oneWeekFromNow = now.plus(Period.weeks(1));
    System.out.println("oneWeekFromNow = " + oneWeekFromNow);
```

Which at the time of writing produces: `oneWeekFromNow = 2013-03-23T14:53:10.681Z`